# I want to fetch values from database to template with the help of session variables

Tags: python, django-views

I got this error in views.py

> type error at line 46 in views.py

```
def edit(request):
    list=[]
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    a = request.session['email']
    b = request.session['password']
    sql1 = "select * from reg where email='%s' and password='%s'" % (a, b)
    cursor.execute(sql1)
    m = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in m:
        dict = {'FirstName':row[1],'LastName':row[2]}
        list.append(dict)
    return render(request, 'predictor/edit.html', {{'list':list}})
```

Comment: It is better to show full traceback.

Comment: Which line is 46?